# How to navigate in comments menu from Vim?

Tags: vim

How do I navigate the menus of this configuration file with Vim? It is the kitty configuration file but Vim shows it to me in the form of chapters by detecting the comments in the file.

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are not menus. They are folds, about which you can read up here: `:help folds`.

To move to next fold: `zj`.

To toggle the current fold: `za`.

To open all folds: `zR`.

Etc.

Comment: I just saw the documentation on folds on Vim. Thank you very much, I really didn't know where to look!